# Sound settings not work on 14.04 but I have sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, alsa, soundcard

Fresh 14.04 install. Everything was fine in 13.10.

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device a002
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at fa200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology Device 0801
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f7000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
```

I can hear sound, but the sound settings show no soundcard. There is no indicator until I uncheck and check the "show sound volume in menu bar" but then it show just muted, sliders have no effect. Media key are also not working. It "thinks" there is no soundcard even when it is working.

Sidequestion: whats are this audio controllers on new graphics cards? Are there just to pass the sound from the real soundcard to the HDMI cable or is it actually a real soundcard in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened but it was working fine after another install. This may have to with me **not** checking "install updates during install" or "enable 3rd party ..." because I left both unchecked.

Comment: I've the same problem! And I don't want to re-install! :/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that alsa mixer works for you too?

On my system, the sounds settings are active only while pulseaudio is running. To start the daemon manually:

```
pulseaudio -D
```

If it gets in the way of something else you can stop it by

```
pulseaudio -k
```